# Utilizar R dentro de um .ipynb

Tags: python, r

Olá! Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Estou precisando utilizar os seguintes pacotes R para um trabalho acadêmico:

1. BETS (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BETS/index.html)
2. getDFPdata (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GetDFPData/index.html)
3. getHFdata (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GetHFData/index.html)

Gostaria de saber se esses pacotes possuem algum equivalente dentro do ambiente Python e, caso não, existe alguma forma pela qual eu possa utilizar tais pacotes dentro de um interpretador Python (arquivo .ipynb)?

Eu queria evitar ter que construir minhas tabelas num scrip no R e depois voltar e importar tais tabelas no Python para então utilizá-las.

Comment: Não costumo utilizar Python, mas um Jupyter Notebook não funcionaria?

Comment: Então, o arquivo .ipynb é o que é gerado após escrever um código no jupyter notebook, mas não sei se num mesmo notebook seria possível escrever em duas linguagens diferentes: Python e R.